# How to Iterate the values in HTML in template

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

Hi I need to iterate the template in the HTML on the basis of certain condition/Values in the Javascript
For example if values in the variable first ='Youth' then the first template should get displayed and if the value by the user input changed to = 'Old' then the second template should get displayed:--

Code  JS and HTML

```
import { LightningElement, api,track } from 'lwc';



export default class ccdeatails extends LightningElement {

    @track first = 'Youth';
    
    //on the basis of user input it gets changed to 'old '
 
}
```

HTML

```
<template if:true ={Youth}>
    <div>This is for Youth</div>
</template>

<template if:true {old}>
     <div>This is for old</div>
</template>
```

Kindly someone help me out for this.not able to get this... if the values

Comment: Hi Trang, Welcome to SFSE! Please help yourself by visiting [ask] page and [edit] your question to add more details and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @rahul ....Sorry i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two properties here. Just write one getter to function to set the visibility conditionally.

```
get isFirst(){
    return this.first === 'Youth' ? true : false;
}
```

In the HTML

```
<template if:true={isFirst}>
    <div>This is for Youth</div>
</template>

<template if:false={isFirst}>
    <div>This is for old</div>
</template>
```